# Brazilian Jiu Jitsu mat size and material for casual 1v1?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, equipment, safety, protective-equipment

I am looking to purchase some mats so that we can do some casual rolling but I'm not really sure what to look for, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

1. What size mats (as in area) would we need to do some rolling starting from our knees? And what size would we need if we were wanting to practice takedowns/throws?
2. What material is viable?
3. How thick should the mat be?

Comment: This questions is related: http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/where-can-i-go-to-order-cheap-grappling-mats-for-beginners

Comment: Thanks, it's kind of related but it's more about where to buy them which unfortunately doesn't really help me as I don't live in the US.

Comment: We use a number of mats that can hold 34 people at max and costs about 5000$. That should give you an idea

Comment: $5000 / 17 = around $300 for 2 people so not too cheap. Can you give me any info on the material you use?

Comment: **Do not answer in comments.**

Comment: Are you replying to a comment from 2 years ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mat size, I am listing the official competition mat sizes as a reference to help you assess the difference between practicing throws and takedowns and practicing ground techniques: keep in mind that these are large competition areas meant to minimize out-of-bound stoppages and injury risks, and they are a reasonable upper bound for a mat used by two people. For a lower bound I would advise not to go below 3mx3m for ground work though, 4mx4m for throws.

Here are the official sizes:

- [Competition Judo mat](http://www.intjudo.eu/editor_up/up/IJF%20REF%20RULES_Final%20print%20vers_2011-12_ENG_Final_amended.pdf) is squared: outer square side 14m-16m, inner square side 8m-10m.
- [Competition BJJ mat](http://ibjjf.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/IBJJF-Rule-Book-v2.0.pdf) is squared: outer square side 8m-10m, inner square side 6m-8m.
- [Competition Wrestling mat](http://www.fila-official.com/images/FILA/reglements/olympique/Wrestling_Rules_June_2013_Eng_final.pdf) has an inner circle, an outer circle and outer big square: outer square side 12m, outer circle diameter 9m, inner circle diameter 7m.

For mat construction of both the floor and side panels, you might want to consider these three layers, starting from lowest:

1. an optional shock absorbtion layer, in order to minimize training injuries from throws. [This one](http://judoamerica.com/coachingcorner/springmat/) ([another example](http://kattaekwondo.com/floor.htm)) is a cheap and effective solution: it is made of tires and plywood. There is [another way](http://judoinfo.com/tatami.htm) that uses foam blocks instead of tires ([source](http://www.mygaragedojo.blogspot.it/), [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzLnsk_HIQY)).
2. a mandatory soft layer, which is the essential layer of your mat. They are usually made of some kind of foam 40mm-50mm thick, there is a wide variety of types; you can find a good discussion [here](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/judo-mats-any-certification-what-characteristics-should-one-look-for).
3. an optional cover for marking areas, good grip, soft layer protection, continuity between soft layer blocks, easy cleaning. They are usually made of vinyl.

Make sure to check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehb7tfvrXe8), it shows pretty much everything said.

Comment: All links have been added, including the mentioned video.